# Exclude Some File Types In Express JS Routing

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I want to match all /admin/* request expect .png, .gif, .js file types. So write this route:

```
app.all('/admin*', requiresLogin);
```

But i can't exclude that file types. How can i exclude .png, .gif, .js request from that routing ?

Answer (score 2):

How about the regex

`\/admin[^.]*\.(?!(?:png|gif|js))`

will exculde .png, .gif, .js

see how the regex matches at http://regex101.com/r/mW5qZ9/1

- `\/admin` matches `/admin`
- `[^.]*\.` matches anything other than `.` followed by `.`
- `(?!(?:png|gif|js))` asserts that the regex is not followed by `png|gif|js`

Answer (score 1):

You could also just set up express to serve your static files so that requests for .png, .gif, .js etc are already completed before this route

```
// will serve pictures and scripts
app.use(express.static('path/to/png/gif/and/js/files'));

// will not see requests like '/admin/happy.gif'
app.all('/admin', requireLogin);
```